# Отфильтрованный список RecyclerView во фрагмент

Tags: android, recyclerview, navigation

Я хочу подгружать в зависимости от выбранной категории разные списки в один recyclerview.
т.е. после нажатия кнопки меню, мне открывается фрагмент с recyclerview и подгруженным в зависимости от выбранной категории списком данных. Как я могу это реализовать?

Comment: у вас есть какая-то архитектура в приложении? больше информации про получение данных и больше конкретики, вопрос получился малость абстрактный.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вижу два варианта: пересоздавать адаптер списка (чтобы меньше нагрузки было) либо полностью пересоздавать фрагмент.

Вариант 1 - вы фильтруете данные через меню, и дальше снова присваиваете данные адаптеру RV. Я не знаю откуда у вас данные берутся, но принцип один и тот же. У вас к примеру на старте список со всеми данными, дальше через меню вы выбираете фильтр и при закрытии меню вы отправляете запрос или как вы там данные получаете, получив данные вы грузите данные в адаптер и говорите ему что данные изменились.

Вариант 2 - вы будете пересоздавать весь фрагмент. Мне кажется этот вариант более громоздким и в итоге он выполняет все то же самое что и первый вариант. Вы выбираете фильтр и шлете через Bundle данные для адаптера. Дальше все так же как и в первом случае.

Какой вариант использовать зависит уже только от вашего выбора.